# How to determine the assumed threading model of a COM class loaded from a side-by-side manifest?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, side-by-side

I know how to determine the threading mode of a COM class that is properly registered in the registry, but what happens in the case when the COM object is loaded from a side-by-side assembly? I know that I must specify the threading model in the manifest but I seem to be running in a weird behaviour during run-time, so I'd like to check what is the assumed threading model of this class before calling `CoCreateInstance`. Are there any Windows APIs to do this (in an ideal case smth like `GetThreadingFromCLSID` :D)?

Comment: Use the "threadingModel" element in the manifest.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I already am. What I was asking for is - is there any way to determine what is threding model that the COM runtime "thinks" the object has. In short - I want to be sure the COM runtime is trying to use the right one.

Comment: Hard to make sense of that, why do you assume it might use the wrong one?  It does not have any choice, the programmer picks it.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, yeah, but for some reason even with `threadingModel="Both"` the object is created on a different thread than `CoCreateInstance` is being invoked from. So I just wanted to know if there is a way I can determine what is the value that COM uses.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: Um, just parse the manifest, and if it doesn't exist then parse the Registry instead. The threading model is specified as part of the COM object's registration, not by the actual COM object itself (since the threading model has to be established before the object is created). Since there is only 2 places where the COM object can be registered, it doesn't seem that hard to figure out how to determine its threading model.